# base element is not working in my local machine

Tags: html, image, href, radix

I'm trying this base element in my local machine, but it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>this is an html base element exampe</title>
        <base href="/home/sugumar/Desktop/html/base.html"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Is it working</p>
        <a href="/images/ptsb.html">click here</a>
        <img src="/images/html5.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

1. link is not working.
2. Image is not showing.

I'm using Debian, and Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: You should use your browser's development tools to debug the issue.  I think you will rapidly see the problem if you check what URLs are being requested.

Comment: Not Found

It shows the error when i click on the link.                     The requested URL /home/sugumar/Desktop/html/images/ptsb.html was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: `Base` refers to a base folder, not a file. It should be the root folder of your `index.html` file

Answer (score 1):

The URL `/home/sugumar/Desktop/html/base.html` is relative to the server root, since it begins with the slash character `/`. When you view a document locally, there is no server, hence no server root, and the effect of setting base URL is thus undefined.

The solution is that you don’t use the `base` element and set addresses relatively to the current document, e.g. `../images/ptsb.html`.